# Prepending “http://” to a URL that doesn't already contain “http://”

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have an input field that saves a URL, I'd like this saved input to recognize when "Http//" is absent from the start of the variable but have no idea where to begin... is it possible to check only a portion of a string? - then have a function that will append if necessary? (IN PYTHON)

example in this field `/article/vijay-and-vijay-sethupathis-master-team-announces-teaser-release-date-137508', '/article/indrajith-sukumaran-starts-shooting-191a-137496`  I want to add  `https://www.thenewsminute.com`
and if the field is like this `https://www.thenewsminute.com/article/soorarai-pottru-review-suriyas-best-outing-long-time-137447` then leave it as it is.

Comment: You can use `str.startswith('https:/')`, and add the prefix if it is missing `s = prefix + s`. Python 3.9 will have `str.removeprefix(prefix)` and `str.removesuffix(suffix)`, but you need to add.

Comment: if not present how to append if present leave with like that

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for prefix with [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=startswith#str.startswith) method:

```
URL = "example.com"
if !URL.startswith("http://"):
    URL = "http://" + URL
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're missing is the 'https://' part you can try this:

```
text = '/article/vijay-and-vijay-sethupathis-master-team-announces-teaser-release-date-137508'

if text[:8] != 'https://':
    text = 'https://www.thenewsminute.com' + text
    print(text)
```

Comment: That's true, I just assumed all the entries are from the same website, https://www.thenewsminute.com, so you wouldn't have to check if it's https:// or http://

Comment: Never assume third party input data!

Comment: I understand that part but if you have more than one website you're getting news from and you are missing the first part, [https://www.cnbc.com] or [https://twitter.com/] etc... it would be impossible to tell which website this following article is from [link]article/4389176-bancfirst-earnings-recovery-likely-to-be-slow. Rereading OP suggests that they're working with only 1 website, otherwise they would've asked how to add more that just [https://www.thenewsminute.com]. to their examples.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to the site, how do I post link of a website without it being automatically formatted into a hyperlink?

Comment: Your comment is unrelated to the problem I pointed out.

Comment: Surround data in backticks.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it, and I think it is related but maybe I'm not explaining it well enough `test`